# Mysterious error with output.nls file and nomencl package

Tags: compilation-error, nomenclature, output, nomencl

I am using an Overleaf template to write my master thesis, which I have to hand in in 2 days. While finalizing the Symbol and Abbreviations List, I had an error while compiling the file. As I could not figure it out, I changed everything back to the original before my changes, but somehow the new error persists. The package used for this list is "nomencl".

I get a warning that my problem is in the outputs.nls file (see below). However, I don't know how to access this file and haven't found any information anywhere else.

The error line in the warnings shows the name of a variable that I deleted completely from the symbol .tex file (*"Rate of Change of the Variable"*), so I don't understand how Overleaf still reads this anywhere while trying to compile. It's like the variable has been saved somewhere, and I can't get rid of it or the error it causes.

I'm not very versed in this package, so any help would be appreciated as this is a very urgent matter for me! Thank you!

[image: error message output.nls]

Comment: use the overleaf button to delete cached generated files

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQBOg.png

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes latex can not step past errors in files generated on a previous run and you need to delete them and allow clean versions to be created.

Overleaf has a button to do this in its "other logs and files" view:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful